# How to generate an array of paired tuples from a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a data frame that contains two columns, one of them contains a sender and the other receiver, example bellow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsT38.png

I am attempting to convert this into an array that contains paired tuples, for example [(1,141),(1,125),...,(149,29)], without manually inputting each of the pairs. I understand how to automatically add elements if this were a regular array, but I don't know how I would do it for tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to answer your question because I don't have enought elements (is your dataframe only have 2 columns?)

if yes, the answer looks like this :

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# use to records to convert dataframe to a record np.array
records = df.to_records(index=False)
# convert to list
result = list(records)
print(result)
```

it'll give you the result you want ONLY if you have a two columns dataframe.